# removeFromSuperview() few subviews

Tags: ios, swift

I have some funcs in `ViewHelper` Class :

```
class func showFrontPopOver(popOver:UIView,view:UIView) {
        let animation = AnimationType.zoom(scale: 1.5)
        popOver.animate(animations: [animation])
        popOver.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        popOver.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(popOver)
    }
class func hidePopOver(popOver:UIView, view:UIView) {
        UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.25, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            popOver.removeFromSuperview()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

And than i call and close my popups(it works perfectly):
[image]

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        ViewHelper.showFrontPopOver(popOver: popOver, view: self.view)
        return true
    }



func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
            ViewHelper.hidePopOver(popOver: self.popOver, view:self.view)
        }
```

But than i want to add a blurView to my `showFrontPopOver` method:

```
class func showFrontPopOver(popOver:UIView,view:UIView) {
    let animation = AnimationType.zoom(scale: 1.5)
    popOver.animate(animations: [animation])
    popOver.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    popOver.center = view.center
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurVisualEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurVisualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)
    view.addSubview(popOver)
}
```

And it turns out that this method does not work:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
                ViewHelper.hidePopOver(popOver: self.popOver, view:self.view)
            }
```

Because he no longer applies to this layer and view.
Probably is not correct that I impose 2 subviews one on another.
But I do not know how to realize the blur effect under my form
[image]

How can i fix it?Close everything, my form and blurView, except maps.

Comment: _Swift Tip:_ Rather then make these `class func`s on a `ViewHelper` class, you could make them extensions on `UIView` so rather than `class func showFrontPopOver(popOver:UIView,view:UIView)`, you'll have `func showFrontPopOver(_ popOver:UIView)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each subview a tag

**op1**

```
class func showFrontPopOver(popOver:UIView,view:UIView) {
    let animation = AnimationType.zoom(scale: 1.5)
    popOver.animate(animations: [animation])
    popOver.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    popOver.center = view.center
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurVisualEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurVisualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    popOver.tag = 11
    blurVisualEffectView.tag = 11
    view.addSubview(blurVisualEffectView)
    view.addSubview(popOver)
}
```

Then

```
class func hidePopOver(popOver:UIView, view:UIView) {
        UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.25, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            view.subviews.forEach {
              if $0.tag == 11 {
                $0.removeFromSuperview()
              }
        }, completion: nil)
 }
```

**op2**

```
class func hidePopOver(view:UIView) {
        UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.25, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            view.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()
            view.subviews.last?.removeFromSuperview()

        }, completion: nil)
 }
```

Comment: thanks Sh_Khan, i just added an action button, and twice close my subs
`@IBAction func choosePopOverAction(_ sender: Any) {
        ViewHelper.hidePopOver(popOver: (view.subviews.last)!, view: self.view)
        ViewHelper.hidePopOver(popOver: (view.subviews.last)!, view: self.view)
    }`